# Rufus-Scheduler, DaemonKit and traps

Tags: ruby, rufus-scheduler, daemons

I daemonized a Ruby scheduler script (using Rufus) with <s>Rufus-Scheduler</s> DaemonKit and I'm trying to trap the TERM or INT signals to have the application try to save state before quitting.

DaemonKit has its own trap_state (private) method and it catches the signal before the daemon script so even though I have this block, it doesn't do much.

```
DaemonKit::Application.running! do |config|

  surprise = Surprise.new(interval, frequency, false)
  surprise.start

  config.trap( 'SIGINT' ) do #tried INT and TERM as well
    puts 'Exiting'
    surprise.stop
    File.delete($lock)
  end
end
```

As a side effect (maybe a mistake in my implementation ?) after sigterm the .rufus lockfile is still there

The behavior on ctrl-c right now is this

```
[daemon-kit]: DaemonKit (0.3.1) booted, now running surprise
log writing failed. can't be called from trap context
[daemon-kit]: Running signal traps for INT
log writing failed. can't be called from trap context
[daemon-kit]: Running shutdown hooks
log writing failed. can't be called from trap context
[daemon-kit]: Shutting down surprise
```

The start method is a pretty simple schedule

```
def start

@scheduler = Rufus::Scheduler.new(:lockfile =>  $lock)

@scheduler.every '1d', :first_at => @first, :overlap => false do |job|
  ... # some work
end

 @scheduler.join
end

def stop
  # save state
  @scheduler.shutdown
end
```

Comment: Sorry, but there is no trap in rufus-scheduler 3.x (rufus-scheduler 2.x had one, but limited to its special SignalScheduler implementation).

Are you sure your `File.delete($lock)` line is reached? Are you sure it would succeed if reached? Place a `puts 'Exited'` at the end of your trap... Wolf fencing.

Comment: @jmettraux ugh I'm stupid, I mixed up DaemonKit and Rufus. It's DaemonKit trapping TERM, my bad

Comment: Please update your explanation then. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @jmettraux yep, done. I found the problem too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it's very simple, I need to configure the trap proc (or block in my case) BEFORE I run the scheduler in the start method. Not feeling very clever right about now, but the following code works as expected. For reference, the set_trap is private in DK but the public trap method overrides the defaults that come with the DK startup.

```
DaemonKit::Application.running! do |config|

  surprise = Surprise.new(interval, frequency, false)

  config.trap("TERM") { surprise.stop }
  config.trap( "INT" ) { surprise.stop }

  surprise.start
end
```

Interestingly I saw this line on startup that I hadn't noticed before

```
[daemon-kit]: Trapping SIGINT signals not supported on this platform
```

INT and TERM both work though

Comment: I see, in `Surprise#start` you call `Scheduler#join` which blocks the running code and the following traps never got set. That is why in this version it works.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your own answer, and the following code you pasted:

```
def start
  @scheduler = Rufus::Scheduler.new(:lockfile =>  $lock)
  # ...
  @scheduler.join # <- NOT NEEDED
end
```

DaemonKit's `DaemonKit::Application.running!` block actually never finishes running, so you could safely skip calling `#join` on any thread.

We should work on making this use-case more clear, as I would love see it used more widely for this kinda work.

Comment: Thanks ! That might be a leftover when I used Rufus on its own before DK. When would I need to join the threads though ?

Comment: In a vanilla Ruby project you'd need to do that. DaemonKit abstracts away the need to keep your script up. It will by hook, or by crook, keep your process alive and running.